# rails.vim with ruby omnicompletion giving "Error loading rails environment" error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, vim, omnicomplete, rails.vim

I'm trying to get up and working with vim with ruby on rails and am having a few problems with omni-completion.

I have downloaded the rails.vim plugin for vim, which appears to be installed, with a vim call

```
:Rails!
```

gives

```
rails.vim 4.3 (Rails-model-arb)
```

Calls to rails.vim specific functions like :Rcontroller work a dream so it all looks very promising. My problem is with omni-completion and syntax highlighting, when I ruby file for example Blog/app/models/post.rb with the following contents

```
1 class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
2   validates :name,  :presence => true
3   validates :title, :presence => true,
4                     :length   => { :minimum => 5 }
5   has_[<C-X><C-O> or <C-X><C-U> or <C-X><C-P>]
6 end
```

I expect supertab to use the rails omni-completion to provide me with options such as "has_many" etc. I'm a little muddled up as to what each of vims completion types do (keyword local completion, omni completion, user defined completion) from the rails documentation it suggests that user defined completion  should provide this functionality. When try  it gives the following error:

```
-- User defined completion (^U^N^P) Pattern not found
Press ENTER or type command to continue
```

when I try  the first time:

```
Error loading rails environment
Problem loading class "Post", was it already completed?
Press ENTER or type command to continue
```

when I try  another time it gives me
    -- Omni completion (^O^N^P) Pattern not found

However omnicompletion does work in many cases, for example if i type meth it will give me a list with method, method_defined?, method_missing, methods to choose from.

Im using pathogen to handle my vim files but my .vimrc file contains the following relavent lines.

```
set nocompatible
call pathogen#helptags()
call pathogen#runtime_append_all_bundles()
syntax on

filetype plugin on
filetype indent on

"set ofu=syntaxcomplete#Complete
set completeopt+=longest,menu,preview

" For code completion with a drop down menu
"au FileType python set omnifunc=pythoncomplete#Complete
let g:SuperTabDefaultCompletionType = "context"
let g:SuperTabContextDefaultCompletionType = "<c-x><c-o>"
let g:SuperTabContextTextOmniPrecedence = ['&omnifunc', '&completefunc']
let g:SuperTabCompletionContexts = ['s:ContextText', 's:ContextDiscover']
let g:SuperTabContextDiscoverDiscovery = ["&completefunc:<c-x><c-u>", "&omnifunc:<c-x><c-o>"]

" If you prefer the Omni-Completion tip window to close when a selection is
" " made, these lines close it on movement in insert mode or when leaving
" " insert mode
autocmd CursorMovedI * if pumvisible() == 0|pclose|endif
autocmd InsertLeave * if pumvisible() == 0|pclose|endif

" Set up java autocompletion
:setlocal completefunc=javacomplete#CompleteParamsInfo
au FileType java set omnifunc=javacomplete#CompleteParamsInfo

" Adding ruby completion??
" Turn on language specific omnifuncs
autocmd FileType ruby,eruby set omnifunc=rubycomplete#Complete
autocmd FileType ruby,eruby let g:rubycomplete_buffer_loading = 1
autocmd FileType ruby,eruby let g:rubycomplete_rails = 1
```

rails.vim is in the ~/.vim/bundle/rails directory, supertab works fine and is installed under ~/.vim/bundle/supertab

I've spent such a long time trying to figure this small thing out but have had no success! Does anyone have any ideas on where I should go from this? I believe it could be something todo with the supertab definitions in the .vimrc file, or the ruby omni-completion definitions.

If I remove the line

```
autocmd FileType ruby,eruby let g:rubycomplete_rails = 1
```

from the .vimrc file the error loading rails error disappears but of course there is no completion of the text, only a user defined completion error.

This is my first post on StackOverflow after a lot of viewing, I hope I have supplied all the relavent details!

I installed vim with MacPorts and my current version is vim @7.3.146_0+huge+perl+python27+ruby, ruby is enabled but macports wanted to install its own version, thus 1.8.7 is installed under /opt/local/ruby despite me using rvm and having 1.9.2 installed with rails 3.0.7. This could perhaps be the problem? I haven't found a way of telling macports to use a version of ruby which is already installed though.

Thanks for all your help!

Comment: I am starting to wonder whether this ability is even expected? Can someone clarify as to whether rails.vim allows for context specific completion, i.e recognising that has_many may belong in that particular location? I have also tried adding a method to the model and attempting to use it with @post.<C-X><C-O> once @post has been instantiated but it doesn't seem to allow this, surely this is a capability that rails.vim provides?

Comment: Could it be something todo with my path? I assumed that nothing would need to be added to it as rails.vim is obviously recognised (hence Rcontroller Post working perfectly)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the ruby completion is being overridden by the java line:

```
:setlocal completefunc=javacomplete#CompleteParamsInfo
```

If I comment that line out I can go into a model and do

```
has_<C-X><C-U>
```

to autocomplete has_many. (You shouldn't even need the `autocmd FileType ruby,eruby ...` lines.)

And yes it's smart in that `n<C-X><C-U>` will give you `named_scope` in a model  but `number_to_currency` and friends in a view.

However rails.vim will not autocomplete custom methods, though I'm sure there are plugins out there that add that.

Comment: Good spot, ofcourse it was not a rails.vim problem but a .vimrc, problem! Cheers.